# Alternative to ELU and Leaky ReLU?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, neural-network, activation-function

I was talking with a friend about different activation functions (we are still new to ML). One thing that I didn't like about ELU was the vanishing gradient, and about Leaky ReLU that it's not differentiable.
I decided to spend a bit of time working in Desmos and came up with this https://www.desmos.com/calculator/jqarpqatyv
Is function this practical in any way? Or is it too expensive/not worth to compute over alternatives?